# R: How to subtract every n-th column from the ones before it in a matrix/data-frame?

Tags: r

let's say I have a matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11   13   15   17
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18
```

I'm looking for an easy way to substract the 3rd column from the 1st and 2nd, then the 6th from the 4th and 5th, and so on.

Can I do this without a for-loop?

Thanks in advance,
   zenzen.

Comment: the documentation will depend on the language it is written in. what language are you writing it in?

Comment: Should the resulting matrix have the same number of columns? I.e. columns 3, 6 etc. will be unchanged?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to point that out. Yes, they should remain unchanged, and the resulting matrix should have the same dimensions.

Comment: @Laurbert515 it is tagged for the R language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer isn't beautiful. It should really be made into a function for clarity, but:

```
m <- matrix(1:18,nrow=5,ncol=9, byrow=TRUE)
colsA <- (1:ncol(m))[1:ncol(m)%%3!=0]
colsB <- (1:ncol(m))[1:ncol(m)%%3==0]
m[,colsA] <- m[,colsA] - m[,rep(colsB,each=2)]
```

no for loop! And the result is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   -2   -1    3   -2   -1    6   -2   -1    9
[2,]   -2   -1   12   -2   -1   15   -2   -1   18
```

edit: here it is as a function

```
nth <- function(x,n) {
  colsA <- (1:ncol(x))[1:ncol(x)%%n!=0]
  colsB <- rep((1:ncol(x))[1:ncol(x)%%n==0], each=n-1)
  x[,colsA] <- x[,colsA] - x[,colsB]
  x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

First I show the principle:

```
x <- matrix(1:20, nrow=2)
x[, seq(1, 7, 3)] <- x[, seq(1, 7, 3)] - x[, seq(3, 9, 3)]
x[, seq(2, 8, 3)] <- x[, seq(2, 8, 3)] - x[, seq(3, 9, 3)]
x

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   -4   -2    5   -4   -2   11   -4   -2   17    19
[2,]   -4   -2    6   -4   -2   12   -4   -2   18    20
```

And next I define a helper function that make a little less typing:

```
myseq <- function(start, object=x){
  seq(start, 3 * (ncol(x) %/% 3), 3)
}

x <- matrix(1:20, nrow=2)
x[, myseq(1)] <- x[, myseq(1)] - x[, myseq(3)]
x[, myseq(2)] <- x[, myseq(2)] - x[, myseq(3)]
x

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   -4   -2    5   -4   -2   11   -4   -2   17    19
[2,]   -4   -2    6   -4   -2   12   -4   -2   18    20
```

Comment: This works, too, but I like Seth's solution even better. But thanks to you, too! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
your_seq <- seq(from=3, to=ncol(your_matrix), by=3)

for(x in 1:length(your_seq)) {
col1 <- your_seq[x] - 1
col2 <- your_seq[x] - 2 
your_matrix[,c(col1,col2)] <- your_matrix[,c(col1,col2)] - your_matrix[,your_seq[x]]
}
```

Comment: If that works, I am surprised.  Or I understood the question incorrectly, because it gives different results to my solution.

Comment: Oops, pressing "Enter" to add a new line is not a good idea... ;-) Is there a more flexible apporach. I have different matrices, so I'd with different numbers of columns.

Comment: Andries solution may be better suited if you have to change the sizes. But this is one of many general solutions for subtracting the 3rd column from every 1st and 2nd before it, so long as the ncol/3 is a whole number.

Comment: Yes, now it works.  The only remaining task is to remove the `for` loop as requested by the OP.

Comment: Why all the hate for `for`, it's still useful!

Comment: @Andrie, he asked if he could do it without a `for` loop. He didn't specify that it was the only solution he was looking for. What's in your bonnet today!?