# Python: How to subtract every n-th column from the ones before it in a matrix/data-frame?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

Basically looking for a similar solution as posted here, but then in python. [R: How to subtract every n-th column from the ones before it in a matrix/data-frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031882/r-how-to-subtract-every-n-th-column-from-the-ones-before-it-in-a-matrix-data-fr)

## Some data

```
import numpy as np
m = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 2], [5, 6, 7, 2]])
```

I want to subtract the value in every 2 columns from the value of the column before. So the solution that I want to end up with two columns. Each row in the first column containing -1 and the second column as [-2, 3, 5]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 2], [5, 6, 7, 2]])

a = m[:,0] - m[:,1]
b = m[:,2] - m[:,3]

m2 = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
print(m2)
```

And for n column :

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3, 5, 5 , 6], [3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2], [5, 6, 7, 2, 7, 1]])

shape = np.shape(m)

print(shape)

result = []
if(shape[1] % 2 == 0):
  for i in range(0, shape[1], 2):
    print(i)
    result.append(m[:,i] - m[:,i+1])

  m2 = result[0]
  for i in range(1, len(result)):
    m2 = np.concatenate((m2, result[i]), axis=1)

  print(m2)
```